# Objective-C style question: do "release" or "nil" properties in dealloc?

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why shouldn't I use Objective C 2.0 accessors in init/dealloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc) 
>   [dealloc, use release or set to nil for properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124049/dealloc-use-release-or-set-to-nil-for-properties)

Hi,

Apple usually release ivars in dealloc but is there anything wrong with nilling the properties in dealloc?

I mean instead of this:

```
- (void) dealoc(){
   [myRetainedProperty release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

write code like this:

```
- (void) dealoc(){
   self.myRetainedProperty = nil;
   [super dealloc];
}
```

I know that it is one additional method call but on the other hand it is safer as it doesn't crashes when you change your property form `retain` to `assign` and forget to amend dealloc.

What do you think? Can you think about any other reason to use release instead of setting to nil besides performance?

**UPDATE:**
It appeared that this question was a duplicate of ["Why shouldn't I use Objective C 2.0 accessors in init/dealloc?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc).

Comment: There's more than one question out there: possible duplicate of [dealloc, use release or set to nil for properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4124049/dealloc-use-release-or-set-to-nil-for-properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something quite similar has already been discussed: [Why shouldn't I use Objective C 2.0 accessors in init/dealloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192721/why-shouldnt-i-use-objective-c-2-0-accessors-in-init-dealloc)

Comment: Thanks for that link it cleared the matter up.

Comment: Vote to close as a duplicate. Then this question will redirect to that one.

Answer (score 1):

i was using the "release" style for quite some time, then i switched to setting the properties to nil afterwards. 
I think if you just release the ivar then you have the chance of reusing it in the dealloc later on, which might not happen but still ... 
Also i consider that setting the properties to nil conforms more to the "encapsulate your ivars with properties" theory ..

So I consider better using the "setting to nil" style, however i don't know any real reasons for using only release ...

Moszi

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, assign nil looks better, until you will forget to write self. before property name :)

Comment: Nice reason :). Fortunately the leak instruments will catch that problem.