# Xcode4 - Declaring an object in header file

Tags: ios, xcode4

For example one, I declare an object inside the interface brace `{}` like:

```
@interface testViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UILabel * myLabel;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) UILabel *myLabel;

@end
```

and example two, I declare an object outside the inferface brace `{}` like:

```
@interface testViewController : UIViewController {
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;

@end
```

I run the code and the result is the same, so I want to ask what is the different for decalare an object inside or outside the interface brace `{}`?

Thanks

Comment: Here is your **[solution..**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635190/declaring-iboutlet-inside-or-outside-interface "Declaring IBOutlet inside or outside @interface?")

Comment: possible duplicate of [Declaring IBOutlet inside or outside @interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635190/declaring-iboutlet-inside-or-outside-interface)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern Objective-C runtimes (64-bit Mac OS X and iOS) will generate the backing store for your declared properties when you `@synthesize` them. So you don't need to declare them within the braces.

If you are declaring an iVar that is not a property and will only be used by the class, then they need to be declared. It's a good idea to mark these `@private` e.g

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
@private
    NSString *privateString;
}
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *publicString; // be sure to @synthesize this
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second example you only declare a property. Xcode will declare object automatically.